# POP3/SMTP on Ubuntu using Linux group

Tags: email, ubuntu, authentication, smtp, pop3

I need to setup a POP3/SMTP server on our Ubuntu server (`example.com`). Now I found postfix useful for this job. Is it possible to let users from the group `users` (on the system) use this service, so they can login with their username/password? For example, if `kevin` is a user from the group `users`, then he can login on the POP3 server and retrieve (and send) mail for `kevin@example.com`? Is it also possible to save the in- and outgoing e-mails in a database?

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ís a link to the [Postfix features](http://www.postfix.org/features.html). I have only found that they store users in the database.

I am using a mailserver configured after the tutorials of [workarounds.org](http://workaround.org/) and have also implemented servers following this solution for a few clients with up to 100 concurrent users for now.

But for example the [DBMail](http://www.dbmail.org/) project offers at least storing mails to databases.